# Dynamically Extracting Data Into a Table Using Nested INDEX MATCH and VLOOKUP Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table structured like this on image:

I'm trying to create a formula in Excel that will extract the correct results from a dataset based on matching criteria in each row, and have that same formula replicate accurately down the entire column.

[image: Dataset]

I need a formula that will lookup the correct "Value" from the source data table and return it in the "Result" column, based on the Month, PID, and Metric matching in each row.

Importantly, I need it to be a single formula that can be auto-filled down the entire "Result" column without issue - the criteria will change with each row, but the formula structure should remain the same.

Can anyone provide an example of a formula, preferably using INDEX/MATCH or similar, that would satisfy these criteria? I'm stuck on how to construct it to dynamically adjust for each row, specifically by month. Also, Columns B&C, D&E are merged for the Months.

Comment: Are you trying to get the `Total` values but if so then it should not be matching by months, as for `January` it is `21` for `PID` `p20111`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Older Versions then using `SUMPRODUCT()` or `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`+`MATCH()` can be used to accomplish the desired output.

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LOOKUP(COLUMN($B$1:$G$1),COLUMN($B$1:$G$1)/($B$1:$G$1<>""),$B$1:$G$1)=$I4)*
  ($J4=$A$3:$A$7)*(K$3=$B$2:$G$2)*$B$3:$G$7)
```

---

Or,

```
=INDEX($B$3:$G$7,MATCH($J4,$A$3:$A$7,0),
  MATCH(1,(LOOKUP(COLUMN($B$1:$G$1),COLUMN($B$1:$G$1)/($B$1:$G$1<>""),$B$1:$G$1)=$I4)*(K$3=$B$2:$G$2),0))
```

---

And using `MAKEARRAY()` which can spill the output as one single dynamic array:

[image]

---

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(I4:J9),COLUMNS(K3:L3),LAMBDA(r,c,
 SUM((SCAN(,B1:G1,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y)))&"|"&B2:G2=
 INDEX(I4:J9,r,1)&"|"&INDEX(K3:L3,c))*(INDEX(I4:J9,r,2)=A3:A7)*B3:G7)))
```

---

Comment: SUMPRODUCT worked, thank you.

Comment: @Sweetcorn glad to know it worked as well!